# JS Conflict Virtuemart Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, conflict, virtuemart

I am having issues getting Virtuemart to run correctly and pretty sure its a js conflict, but have been struggling to figure it out. The issue is the states will not populate when country is chosen in checkout dropdown here is a link: http://tinyurl.com/os7h9p2

I have tried turning off modules and plugin and have had no luck. I can change the template and the above issue goes away so something in my template is causing an error. I tried removing the java calls from the template and the template will not run.

Has anyone run ito this before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you're having two JS libraries: MooTools and jQuery which are conflicting. The solution would be to include in your page the following js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
</script>
```

read more about it:

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Would this code have to be in a certain place? I have it added about line 65 here: http://www.teamkalitta.com/kalitta-motorsports-checkout-2/editaddresscartBT.html did not seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have 2 versions of jquery being imported. 1 by your template, and the other by VirtueMart. This can cause conflicts.
I'm not sure where about VirtueMart import jQuery, but I assume your template will be doing it in the `index.php` file.

Try to locate the line that imports jQuery which should be something like this:

```
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/hexicon_gamer/js/jquery/jquery.min.js");
```

and replace with the following:

```
<?php
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
     $doc->addScript($s5_directory_path.'/js/jquery/jquery.min.js');
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Ladder Here is the code in place now:

 <?php
 s5_mootools_call();
 //Calls jquery javascript
 if($version->RELEASE >= '3.0'){
 JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
 }
 $doc=JFactory::getDocument();
 if($version->RELEASE <= '2.5'){
 $doc->addScript($s5_directory_path.'/js/jquery/jquery.min.js');
 } ?>

Comment: I changed it to <?php
s5_mootools_call();
//Calls jquery javascript
 if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/hexicon_gamer/js/jquery/jquery.min.js");
  } ?>

I get a blank screen